# Google charts Gantt show x-axis (calendar) on top

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

As per title, Does anybody know how to move the calendar of the chart from the bottom to the top of the chart?

Comment: there are no options to change the position of the x-axis, you would have to manually manipulate the chart's svg elements. after the chart has been drawn

Comment: How do you suggest to manipulate the svg? I see from inspect elements that they seem to be <text> as well as every other label in the chart area, how can I discriminate against them?

Comment: when the chart's `'ready'` event fires, you can change the x attribute of the text element, you can sometimes use the `text-anchor` attribute to differentiate from the others, or use font color, whatever is available -- but if you move the text elements up, you'll most likely have to move all other elements down...